# Build in two machines

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have a c++ application. For a release build we use two machines. In the first machine we build the visual studio solution and checkin the binary and pdb files to svn. In the second machine we take the binaries from svn and create the installation using install shield.

Can we automate the build activity with cruise control?

What step should I follow for this?

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer*:

Yes, if you can write a bat file (or similar) that performs the build cruise control can run it.

*Long answer*:

If this is doable or not depends on if the build process is possible to automate. The best way to determine that is to try it out in small chunks.

- Determine the commands you need to run to produce the binary (might be as simple as an `msbuild`/`nant` call)
- Determine the commands you need to run to produce the install file given a binary.
- If you really need to do this on two separate machines:

  - Make a command that can take build results and commit them to svn, keeping track of the revision number.
  - Make a command on the installer production server that can check out a given revision number.
  - Make a command that remotely calls the installer command and passes a revision number to it.
  - Make sure you have an automated way to pick up the build artifact from the install server and store it in a defined place.